# MissingReferenceException makes no sense

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am getting `MissingReferenceException` but it doesnt make sense, since I am destroying a `GameObject`, but I never mention it in the code again.

The whole error in console:

> MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been
>   destroyed but you are still trying to access it.

```
Transform[] currentShips = shipParent.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

if (currentShips.Length > 0)
{
    foreach (Transform obj in currentShips)
    {
        Destroy(obj.gameObject);
    }
}
```

It doesn't make sense to me since there is no other references to `currentShips` (and also of course not to `obj`, since its local). I also tried checking if `currentShips != null` in the `if` statement, but no change. I am guessing its just a little simple thing I am overlooking, but thats what this site is made for, right?

Comment: The stack trace include the line where this error occurs, check it.

Comment: Are there any other places in code where you destroy gameobjects?

Comment: The problem is that it doesnt show any line, im on the bus atm but when I'll get home i will send a screenshot.

Comment: This snippet is from a big method for my battleships game, like i said i am on the bus and cant check, but i am pretty sure this is the only place. Its to destroy old ships so a new random arrangement can be instantiated.

Comment: try a for loop not foreach and by preference start at the end and work back to position 0

Comment: Is it possible that this peace of code is called more than one time?

Comment: GetComponentsInChildren retrieves the game object itself as well. So I think `shipParent` itself is destroyed with all its children and afterwards the next child in loop crashes. Try using `foreach (Transform child in transform)` instead to get the child objects without the parent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you get here is a Unity built-in special form of a `NullReferenceException` just that after destroying the reference in Unity isn't actually `null` but still stores some information e.g. the **why** it is `null`.

So checking `currentShips != null` doesn't do anything since the exception doesn't come from here. It is probably rather in the line

```
Destroy(obj.gameObject);
```

where `obj` was already destroyed!

---

The actual issue was mentioned already in the comments by Kay and also on the deleted answer by Adriani6:

```
shipParent.GetComppnentsInChildren<Transform>()
```

**includes the `Transform` component of the `shipParent` object itself!!**

> Returns all components of Type `type` **in the `GameObject`** or any of its children.

Additionally it is most likely that the `shipParent`'s `Transform` is the very first one to be found and destroyed! So in the next iteration all child `obj` are already also marked as destroyed.

---

Instead you should use

```
foreach (Transform obj in shipParent.transform)
{
    Destroy(obj.gameObject);
}
```

this built-in enumeration iterator for the `Transform` type does exactly what you would expect: Returns all first level children's `Transform` reference.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work. Destroying a list of objects should start from the last item. Foreach is not suitable for this, because it starts from the beginning of the list. When you destroy almost half of the objects, the count of the remaining objects won't match the index of the next object to be destroyed.

```
    Transform[] currentShips = shipParent.GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>();

    if (currentShips.Length > 0)
    {
        int objCount = currentShips.Length;
        for (int i = objCount - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            Destroy(currentShips[i].gameObject);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Won't make a difference as the actual problem is the `GetComponentsInChildren` call itself (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58623677/7111561))